# How to declare a templated function with an optional compile-time parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

I want a function with this interface.

```
func<Type1,CompileOption>( Type2 value)
//or
func<Type1>( Type2 value)
```

The first compile-time parameter is a type.  It is require in every function call.
The second compile time parameter is optional.  It is used to modify the behavior of `func`.
The function itself is templated on the regular parameter's type (`Type2`).

Can an interface like this be built?

If it cannot is there a way to get similar behavior?  eg something that acts like a templated function that takes two compile-time parameters, where the second is optional?

The naive approach doesn't work.

```
// invalid syntax
template< typename Type1, typename CompileOption = Default, typename Type2>
void func( Type2 t2 );

// Does the wrong thing.
// CompileOption Parameter now change Type2.
template< typename Type1, typename Type2, typename CompileOption = Default>
void func( Type2 t2 );

//This kinda expresses what I'm looking for
template<typename Type2>
template<typename Type1, typename Optional = Default >
void func( Type2 t2 );
```

Comment: The first option is not invalid syntax. Assuming you use a C++0x compiler (since you seem to be allowed to use default template arguments in function templates), you can also use default arguments for non-trailing template parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I over thought the problem and confused everyone else as well.  It's not possible to write one function unless C++0x extensions are used.  However it's quite straight forward to write it with two overloaded functions.

```
template< typename Type1, typename Option, typename Type2 >
void func( Type2 t2 )
{ /* ... */ }

template< typename Type1, typename Type2 >
void func( Type2 t2 )
{ func<Type1,Default,Type2>(t2); }

func<int,fast_t>(20.f);
func<float>(30); // uses Default as Option
func<float,Default>(30); //exact same call as above.
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?

```
template<typename Type1, typename Type2, typename Option>
void foo (Type2 arg)
{
    ... code ...
}

template<typename Type1, typename Type2>
void foo (Type2 arg)
{
    foo<Type1, Type2, DefaultOption>(arg);
}
```

Edit: The above snippet works, but has the drawback that Type2 needs to be explicitely specified in the calls.

I have to admit that I can't think of a good full-template solution for this; the closest I could get was using empty method arguments:

```
struct DefaultOption { ... } DEFAULT;
struct OtherOption { ... } OTHER;

template<typename Type1, typename Type2, typename Option>
void foo (Type2 arg, Option)
{
    ... code ...
}

template<typename Type1, typename Type2>
void foo (Type2 arg)
{
    foo<Type1, Type2>(arg, DEFAULT);
}
```

This allows calls in the form

```
foo<std::string>(1, DEFAULT);
foo<std::string>(1.0, OTHER);
foo<std::string>("Hello");
```

I'm curious as to what the real answer to this puzzle is.

Comment: Close to what I want but not quite.  It want to be able to call `foo` like this: `foo<int,Fast_t>(42)`, or `foo<int>(42.f)`.

Comment: Indeed. I edited my answer accordingly, but sadly it's still not quite what you have in mind.

Comment: Can't you switch the order of template arguments? `template <class Type1, class Option, class Type2>`?

Comment: *duh* That works! Write it up as an answer, so you can get credit for it.

Answer (score 1):

You could always try

```
template<typename Type1, typename Optional = Default >
struct A
{
    template<typename Type2>
    void func( Type2 t2 ) {
        // function body
    }
};
```

Maybe this is what you need.